# Android manifest and <compatible-screens>

Tags: android, android-manifest

I publish my app on the play store but it is not one thing clear.

I put in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens = "false"
    android:normalScreens = "true"
    android:largeScreens = "false"
    android:xlargeScreens = "false" />
```

Now, if i add this code:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

I have the drawable-mdpi,hdpi and xhpdi folders. If I put the tag   and phone normalscreen has a density of xhdpi , will use the resources present in the drawable-xhdpi folder?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It doesn't look like it changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will, but on the other hand incompatible devices, i.e. other than normal, or xxhdpi and so on, won't be able to use your app.

It all varies across devices, you can have a `large` device that has low density. You'd use the `large` modifiers to create layout folders for specific sizes and at the same time drawables for different screen densities.

```
res/
    layout/
        main.xml  // standard layout
    layout-large/
        main.xml  // devices classified as "large" will load this layout
```

Suppose we have a tablet, it's going to load layout from `layout-large` folder, whereas a phone would load `layout`. But at the same time, if they have the same densities, for example `xhdpi`, both versions will use drawables located in `drawable-xhdpi` folder.

Here's an [article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) that describes everything there is to know about adapting your app's resources to different displays.

Comment: So it's okay to have an image of 54 pixels for hdpi and 64 pixels  xhdpi for a phone with a noralscreen? For a phone with a normalscreen i think that 64px is much. No?

Comment: @Raffa You have to resolve it by providing different layouts. Different layouts probably will also mean using different drawables for them, but it may well be that they just need to be placed differently. I can't relate to the image size itself, because it is intrinsic to your application. The whole idea behind different layouts for different screen sizes is to utilize additional space larger displays are giving.